# Manually Cropping a UIImage after click from Camera in iOS SDK

Tags: camera, uiimage, drag, crop

I want to crop the image which I click from camera with touch and want to drag that copped image to some else snap(e.g Replacing head in image with my head), for that I need to know how I can crop the image so that I can get my head cropped from clicked image. Please give me some way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by another technique. I didn't crop the image.